# Javascript not running - no error message

Tags: javascript

I've set up this rock, paper scissors game. However, the Javascript is not running and I'm not receiving any errors. Any suggestions?

```
function play(humanScore) {     
    var computerScore = getcomputerScore();

    if (humanScore == "rock") {
        if (computerScore == "rock") {
        } else if (computerScore == "scissors") {
            human++
        } else if (computerScore == "paper") {
            computer++
        }
    } else if (humanScore == "scissors") {
        if (computerScore == "scissors") {
        } else if (computerScore == "paper") {
            human++
        } else if (computerScore == "rock") {
            computer++
        }
    } else if (humanScore == "paper") {
        if (computerScore == "paper") {
        } else if (computerScore == "scissors") {
            computer++
        } else if (computerScore == "rock") {
            human++
        }
    }
}

function getcomputerScore() {
    var randomplay = ["rock", "paper", "scissors"];
    var play = randomplay[Math.floor(Math.random() * myArray.length)];
    return play 
}
```

This is the code setting up `humanScore`:

```
var human = 0;
var computer = 0;

document.getElementById("rock").onClick = pickRock;
document.getElementById("scissors").onClick = pickScissors;
document.getElementById("paper").onClick = pickPaper;

function pickRock() {
    play("rock");
}

function pickScissors() {
    play("scissors");
}

function pickPaper() {
    play("paper");
}
```

Comment: Please put this into a [**JSFiddle**](http://www.jsfiddle.net)

Comment: You haven't provided your HTML, so we can't really tell if you're doing something to call those functions.

Comment: In the *getcomputerScore* function you do `myArray.length`, where does that come from? I think you mean to use `randomplay.length`.

Answer (score 0):

The name of the property is `onclick`, not `onClick`; note the lowercase `c`.

There’s at least one other error (`myArray.length`, as @RobG points out), but this will make them actually throw.

Comment: HTML attribute names are case-insensitive. `onclick` is preferred (perhaps for compatibility with XHTML), but `onClick` will work.

Comment: @Barmar: I’m talking about the property; the OP deleted the comment with the setup code for some reason (maybe because it didn’t show up formatted?). I’ve put it back in the question.

Comment: Oops, sorry, didn't see that.

Answer (score 0):

Probably better suited to a code review section, but here goes…

```
function play(humanScore) {
    var computerScore = getcomputerScore();
```

variables *humanScore* and *computerScore* aren't actually scores, they are symbols the players have chosen to play, so the variables might be better as *humanChoice* and *computerChoice*. This also means that the globals *human* and *computer* can be better named as *humanScore* and *computerScore*.

```
if (humanScore == "rock") {
    if (computerScore == "rock") {
    } else if (computerScore == "scissors") {
```

Rather than leaving a blank block, better to either insert a comment to say "no adjustment". Better to test equivalent choices up front, then you're left with binary choices, so you can do something like:

```
var humanScore = 0;
var computerScore = 0;

function play(humanChoice) {

  // IE tends to play with capitalisation of values
  humanChoice = humanChoice.toLowerCase(); 
  var computerChoice = getComputerChoice();

  // If same choice, no change of score
  if (computerChoice == humanChoice) {
    return;
  }

  // Only binary win/lose choices left
  if (humanChoice == 'rock') {
    computerChoice == 'paper'? ++computerScore : ++humanScore;

  } else if (humanChoice == 'paper') {
    computerChoice == 'scissors'? ++computerScore : ++humanScore;

  } else if (humanChoice == 'scissors') {
    computerChoice == 'rock'? ++computerScore : ++humanScore;
  }
}
```

There was an error in this function too:

```
function getComputerChoice() {
  var choices = ['rock','paper','scissors'];
  return choices[Math.random()*choices.length | 0];
}
```

Lastly, make sure the buttons are in the page before adding the listener, and make sure the property names have the correct case (it doesn't matter for HTML attributes, but it does for javascript property names):

```
window.onload = function() {
  document.getElementById("rock").onclick = pickRock;
  document.getElementById("scissors").onclick = pickScissors;
  document.getElementById("paper").onclick = pickPaper;
}
```